# Yup how to validate mandatory fields on null object

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I have a problem regarding the validation of mandatory fields which are properties of a (possibly) null object.

Here is an example schema :

```
object().shape({
   catalog: {
      brand: string().required()
   }
})
```

If I try to validate the following object against this schema, I get the expected error : brand is required. From what I understood, there is a default value created for undefined object which mimics the shape of the object in the schema. This is the behavior I expected and what I want.

```
{ catalog: undefined }

// "catalog.brand is a required field"
```

But in my case, I don't receive an object with undefined, but with null. And I can't figure out how to manage the same result with a null value.

```
{ catalog: null }

// No error on catalog.brand
```

Manually casting null to undefined is out of the question as there is a good reason why I receive null.

Here is a codesandbox which reproduces my use case :

https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-playground-tbfcj

I would really appreciate a bit of help on this, thanks :)

Comment: Did you finds any solution? I am fighting with the same problem right now.

Comment: @DávidM. the only way I found to get past the problem is to cast null to undefined in my validators :/ I didn't post it because I don't think it's a good way to solve the problem but I don't have anything else at the moment. It looks like this : catalog: object().transform(nullToUndefined). nullToUndefined just checking if my value is undefined and returning null it that's the case.

Comment: I was casting null to undefined in my initial values before, so your solution is way better. And working! Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to include both `nullable()` and `required()` to the shape.

Example

```
const requiredOption = Yup.object()
  .shape({
    value: Yup.string(),
    label: Yup.string(),
  })
  .nullable()
  .required('This field is required.');
```

Comment: Is it fine to have both .nullable() and .required() for You.string() ? so basically use case it is a mandatory field (string value), but server sends value as null

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `strict()` on your object schema

```
object().shape({
   catalog: {
      brand: string().required()
   }
}).strict();
```

Comment: Amedeo is always the best!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a less mindbending way to do it than the other answer. This allows you to keep the `required` directive on the `subfield` whether or not the parent schema/field containing it is empty at validation time.

```
yup.object().shape({
  field: yup.object().shape({
    subfield: string().required(),
  }).default(undefined),
});

// Or...

yup.object().shape({
  field: yup.object().shape({
    subfield: string().required(),
  }).default(null).nullable(),
});
```

One difference between the two is that when you `validate` data over each of these schemas and `field` is missing, if you also pass in `stripUnknown`, in the first case the field will be totally removed from the validated result, but in the second case the field will still show up but with value `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `.default(null)` method along with `.nullable()` worked for me.

```
const parentValidator = Yup.object({
  personData: personDataValidator,
  data: Yup.object({
    workshift: Yup.array()
      .of(Yup.string().matches(/x|-/g, "Local de trabalho inválido"))
      .required("Turno de trabalho obrigatório")
      .typeError("Turno de trabalho inválido"),
    workplace: Yup.string()
      .required("Local de trabalho obrigatório")
      .typeError("Local de trabalho inválido"),
    email: Yup.string()
      .required("Email obrigatório")
      .typeError("Email inválido"),
  }),
})
  .default(null)
  .nullable();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).